# Is there a simple way in swiftui to create a 3 tier master-context-detail application like Mail?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I’m building my first app in swiftui and I’ve got an iPhone version working nicely using a `stackNavigationViewStyle` navigation view. However when used in landscape mode on large screens or on an iPad it gets distorted and a better use of that screen real estate would be to show the navigation.

I have tried a `DoubleColumnNavigationViewStyle` and that gets me two columns but the second tier of navigation is still very wide and is replaced by the content when you choose something.

Ideally there would be a default “unselected” view displayed underneath everything and then the navigation on large devices would remain, showing the content in a thinner column on the right. On smaller screens the nav would replace each other on the left and on smallest screens it would be nav or content, one at a time.

I’m just wondering if this or any similar behaviour with 3 tier apps is possible in swiftui or if I’m going to have to jump in with both feet to full fat swift to get this behaviour going. I’ve done quite a bit of searching and I can’t find much, maybe because I’m using the wrong terms.

Thanks!

Edit: Here's the code

ChooseBoatView.swift

```
struct ChooseBoatView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            ZStack {
                BoatList(boats: BoatData())
                    .navigationBarTitle("Choose vessel")
            }
        }
        .navigationViewStyle(DoubleColumnNavigationViewStyle())
    }
}

struct Boat: Decodable, Identifiable {
    var id  = UUID()
    var name: String
    var listIcon: String
    var headerImage: String
    var topics: [Topic]
    
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case name = "name"
        case listIcon = "listIcon"
        case headerImage = "headerImage"
        case topics = "topics"
    }
}

struct BoatRow: View {
    var boat: Boat
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationLink(destination: ChooseTopicView(boat: boat)) {
            HStack {
                Image(decorative: boat.listIcon).resizable()
                    .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                    .frame(minWidth: 0,
                           maxWidth: .infinity,
                           minHeight: 0,
                           maxHeight: .infinity)
                Text(boat.name)
                    .frame(minWidth: 0,
                           maxWidth: .infinity,
                           minHeight: 0,
                           maxHeight: .infinity,
                           alignment: .trailing)
            }
        }
    }
}

struct BoatList: View {
    var boats: [Boat]
        
    var body: some View {
        return List(boats, rowContent: BoatRow.init)
    }
}
```

ChooseTopicView.swift

```
struct ChooseTopicView: View {
    var boat: Boat
    var body: some View {
        if #available(iOS 14.0, *) {
            TopicList(topics: boat.topics)
                .navigationBarTitle(boat.name, displayMode: .inline)
        } else {
            TopicList(topics: boat.topics)
                .navigationBarTitle(boat.name)
        }
    }
}

struct Topic: Decodable, Identifiable {
    var id  = UUID()
    var name: String
    var image: String
    var boatName: String
    var policyLink: String
    var policyLinkDescription: String
    var videoLink: String
    
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case name = "name"
        case image = "image"
        case boatName = "boatName"
        case policyLink = "policyLink"
        case policyLinkDescription = "policyLinkDescription"
        case videoLink = "videoLink"
    }
}

struct TopicRow: View {
    var topic: Topic
    var body: some View {
        NavigationLink(destination: TopicView(topic: topic)) {
                Image(decorative: topic.image)
                    .resizable()
                    .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
                    .frame(minWidth: 0,
                           maxWidth: .infinity,
                           minHeight: 0,
                           maxHeight: .infinity)
                    .background(Color(.white))
                    .clipped()
                Text(topic.name)
                    .frame(minWidth: 0,
                           maxWidth: .infinity,
                           minHeight: 0,
                           maxHeight: .infinity,
                           alignment: .trailing)
                    .multilineTextAlignment(.trailing)
        }.frame(maxHeight: 100.0)
    }
}

struct TopicList: View {
    var topics: [Topic]
    
    var body: some View {
        if(topics.count > 0) {
            List(topics, rowContent: TopicRow.init)
        } else {
            Text("No topics available yet for this vessel")
        }
    }
}
```

Topic itself can be any view.

I think it would be enough either to make the secondary nav replace the primary instead of appearing as the detail, but if there's a way to make all 3 columns appear that would be ideal.

Comment: Include the code you used and images of what that produced. Then we know what we are trying to fix

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A three-tier view is possible in iPadOS, but you have to give your NavigationView three subviews to initialize it, otherwise it will fall back to the two-pane version. For example:

```swift
NavigationView {
  SidebarView()
  Text("List placeholder")
  Text("Detail placeholder")
}
```

Any `NavigationLink` destination links will populate the column where "List placeholder" will appear in the example above. And if that is a list with its own `NavigationLinks`, they will appear in place of the detail placeholder.

Note that in this configuration on iPad, the sidebar will typically be off-screen by default, but can be brought onscreen by hitting the back button above the list or swiping from the left edge. Although iOS 15 brings some minor improvements to three-pane handling on iPad, there's still a way to go to bring it up to a level with a native UIKit implementation.

Note that you probably won't want to use exactly the same navigation on smaller devices - either iPhone screens, or a split-screen or SlideOver iPad view. So you might want a higher level view that looks at our window size classes, and only implements a three-tier navigation view for iPad views that have the width to support them.